# Can caching an API based on the hash of the whole URL be a potential threat?

Tags: api, rest, caching

I am adding caching to an API server. The implementation of the caching system of the framework I am using simply hashes the whole URL of the request and uses it as a cache key (as well as some other data like language, etc..).

But with this simple system I can add fake query parameters to the url with arbitrary values and my system will also cache those requests. For example:

```
GET https://example.com/apicall          # Cached
GET https://example.com/apicall?fake=1   # Also cached
GET https://example.com/apicall?fake=2   # Also cached!
```

Is this something I should worry about? That people can very easily fill my cache with junk entries that aren't used? Or am I exaggerating the potential impact of this?

Comment: It depends on whether the underlying system can handle the load w/o the cache. An adversary could submit those junk URLs and, if using LRU, disable the cache for all users by spamming it. However you might compensate by rate limiting IPs, etc. to avoid various brute force attacks. Overall its likely okay for a low target app, but you made a good observation and could add some safeguards.

Comment: Alright so I have been trying to come up with ways of safeguarding this and well, rate limiting IPs is the only thing that sounds feasible. Validating the query parameters seems to be impossible when they get slightly more complex. Anything else you might suggest? It would be great if you could post a simple answer with ways to safeguard against this.

Comment: I suppose you are building a caching reverse proxy? You might ask those communities how they tackle this problem (nginx, haproxy, etc). Their prior art might lead to a good solution. Otherwise I'd invest in a better eviction policy, such as [W-TinyLFU](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Efficiency) can efficiently filter out one-hit wonders. The other gotcha is to ensure that the key's hash code includes the full url, e.g. I recently [discovered](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1855826) a HashDoS attack because of a misbehaving route cache.